# If-break in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to figure out the equivalent of this Java in Clojure:

```
public int compute(int x) {
    if (x < 0) return 0;    

    // continue do some computing
    return result;
}
```

Is there idiomatic Clojure that "break" processing within a function and return a result?

Comment: (if) form? (if test (when-true) (when-false))

Comment: I suggest working through a tutorial or looking at code examples to gain a minimal understanding of control flow in Clojure. Then, you can ask a better question if still not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no short-circuit `return` statement (or `break` or `goto` ... ). Return is implicit.

A near equivalent in Clojure to your example is

```
(defn test [x]
    (if (< x 0)
        0
        (let [result (comment compute result)]
            result)))
```

But you would probably return `result` without naming it:

```
(defn test [x]
    (if (< x 0)
        0
        (comment compute result)))
```

These run, but the `comment` always evaluates to `nil`.

By the way, the `if` construct with two expressions (rather than the full three) returns `nil` if the test fails.

```
(if (< 3 0) 0) ; nil
```

So there is always something to return.

Answer (score 5):

One of the main guiding principals when programming with Clojure is that everything "returns" a value, though it is usually expressed as "everything evaluates to something". When calling a function the result of the function is the **result of the last expression** in the function.

```
user> (defn foo [] 1 2 3 4)  
#'user/foo 
user> (foo)
4
```

There are several forms for expressing the idea of "stopping early":

```
user> (defn compute [x] (cond (< x 0) 0  :default (* x 42))) 
#'user/compute
user> (compute 1) 
42
```

or

```
user> (defn compute [x] (if-let [y (< x 0)] (* 8 y) (* 4 x))) 
#'user/compute
user> (compute 1) 
4
```

or a simple `if` expression. The important concept being that everything results in a new value. This has spawned many buzwords in the clojure community including "value oriented programming"

Answer (score 2):

Clojure doesn't have a return statement as such, but you can achieve similar results by just having a very simple branch of code on an if statement.

```
(defn compute [x]
    (if (< x 0) 0
       (do ...
           result)))
```

You could also do something similar with `cond` or the maybe monad.

Comment: `0` is not an empty branch, it is just a very simple one

Answer (score 2):

You really need to specify the:

```
// continue do some computing
```

An example..

```
public int test(int x) {
    if (x < 0) 
       return 0;    

    int tmp = getSomthing1(x);
    int tmp2 = getSomething2(x, tmp);
    int result = tmp/tmp2;
    return result;
}
```

This would be somthing like:

```
(defn test [x]
    (if (< x 0)
        0  
        (let [tmp (getSomthing1 x)
              tmp2 (getSomething2 x tmp)]
           (/ tmp tmp2))))
```

What you have is a `(if predicate consequent alternative)` and the `let` can hold intermediate calculations without turning the code imperative.